How to create azure key vault secret with underscore in name using Terraform?
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret001" {
name         = "VccbSettingsV2__EndpointUrl"
value        = "https://some-url.com"
key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}

I get the error when using terraform plan that name cannot contain underscore , perhaps it allows dashes in names but that won't resolve to VccbSettingsV2:EndpointUrl for a dotnet application.

You can't use underscores in Azure Key Vault secret names.
As per Object Identifiers, secret names must be a 1-127 character string, starting with a letter and containing only 0-9, a-z, A-Z, and -.

I got the solution. For a dotnet application to read from Azure key vault, I would require to add secret names as

VccbSettingsV2--EndpointUrl

This double hyphen in terraform specifies that the secret represents the configuration section.
